# How to check if character string is present in column that is not alphanumeric?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, character, string-matching

I have df that looks like this:

```
id    col1 
1     [[[[[[['metal', 'soundtracks'], 'jazz'], 'indie'], 'hiphop'], 'rock'], 'pop'], 'electronic']
```

I want to apply my logic if the character `[` is present. How would I do this?

I tried:

```
df['col1'].str.contains('[').any()
```

but I get error:

```
error: unterminated character set
```

Also tried following combinations:

```
df['col1'].str.contains("[").any()
df['col1'].str.contains("'['").any()
df['col1'].str.contains('"["').any()
```

All getting the same error.

I have confirmed the dtype of the column in question is `object`

My goal is to scan for the symbol `[` and apply my logic to clean up the data.

```
if df['col1'].str.contains('[').any():
                 my logic
```

Also tried forcing the column to string like so but got the same answer:

```
df.col1 = df.col1.astype(str)
```

edit:

Tried this:

if df['col1'].str.contains('[', regex=False).any() == True:

```
    my logic
else:
    print('all good')
```

I am getting a false on the `if` statement even though the character is present

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is problem `[` is special regex character, so is necessary parameter `regex=False`:

```
df['col1'].str.contains('[', regex=False).any()
```

Or escape value by `\`:

```
df['col1'].str.contains('\[').any()
```

Comment: @RustyShackleford - Some problem?

Comment: even with the character in the column value, I am getting false. What could be the reason for this? editing column to show full value

Comment: @RustyShackleford - There should be some lists, try convert to strings before test like `df['col1'].astype(str).str.contains('[', regex=False).any()`